# Modify global Window Variable in Angular 6 Tests

Tags: angular, testing, protractor, initialization, e2e-testing

I'm trying to test an end-to-end process in an Angular 6 app using e2e and protractor.  I have a service that injects some javaScript into the page, so my tests verify that the script has been appended to the DOM.

The wrinkle is that the service checks a configuration object that is hard-coded in the index.html file.  I have to set one particular property to false in order for my tests to run, but so far, I haven't managed to find a way to hook into the app initialization process.

I can get at the property using code such as this:

```
browser.wait(
  browser.executeScript('return window.Config.local;')
         .then(promise => expect(promise).toBe(false)
), 5000);
```

But the question is where to put the call!

I have put some time into using APP_INITIALIZER, but the only way that I could get it to work was by setting it in the app.module.ts file.  I'd rather not change its contents for test purposes.

I would be most appreciative if anyone had any idea how to get at the window object before the app fully initializes.  I have spent three full days on this now and still no solution...

Thanks!

Comment: Can you not conditionally use the APP_INITIALIZER in app module based on an environment key? Yes, it would be in your code base, but it will only run with a test flag set. Also, APP INIT doesn’t have to be in your app module, it could also live in a feature module which you could also exclude on a prod build.

Comment: I created a component called TestsInitializerModule.  I don't suppose there's a way to dynamically load my module without including it in app.module.ts imports?

Comment: No, probably not. However, you could dynamically import it inside your module import definitions so it will only be imported when runnig your test.

Comment: Again, what is your question?

Comment: Dynamically importing the module is a lot of work for a test! Unless someone comes up with a brilliant idea, I think that using a feature module is going to be the solution. :-)

Comment: What would be the best way to pass a parameter to the APP_INITIALIZER hook method?  I would like it to run only for e2e tests and I have to initialize the window.Config.local property to true for one test and false for another.

Comment: I just realized that I can't access the window.Config.local property from the APP_INITIALIZER hook method.  The whole build blows up if I attempt to reference the protractor browser.  Perhaps APP_INITIALIZER is too soon in the process.  ANY IDEAS???